# What does swi SYS_ERROR0 do in arm linux kernel?

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, arm, kernel

Below is the code for reset vector as defined arm linux (arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S)

```
vector_rst:
 ARM(   swi     SYS_ERROR0      )
 THUMB( svc     #0              )
 THUMB( nop                     )
        b       vector_und
```

What does the instruction `swi SYS_ERROR0` do ? When I checked, I found SYS_ERROR0 in arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.c

```
DEFINE(SYS_ERROR0,            0x9f0000);
```

I was unable to find anything related to it on internet. Can someone explain what does this instruction do ? What is `SYS_ERROR0` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was unable to find anything related to it on internet. Can someone explain what does this instruction do ? What is SYS_ERROR0 ?

```
DEFINE(SYS_ERROR0,            0x9f0000);
```

The [`swi` instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204f/Cihidabi.html) is typically a call from user mode to system mode.  Ie, User space to the Linux kernel.  Lower numbers are standard Linux system call such as `open()`, `sbrk()`, etc.

If you look at [uapi/asm/unistd.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/include/uapi/asm/unistd.h) in *arch/arm* you can see some defines like `__ARM_NR_BASE` which is `__NR_SYSCALL_BASE+0x0f0000`.  This can be 0x9f0000 for OABI systems.  Basically, these are *secret* system calls that are ARM specific kernel calls.  For instance, `__ARM_NR_get_tls` is only used for *libc* thread management on the ARM.  Other CPUs may have different non-syscall mechanisms to do the same thing and/or the syscall interface may be different than on the ARM CPU.

So `SYS_ERROR0` is a special ARM system call.  By the way, *asm-offset.c* is never used directly.  It is compiled and the object is scanned by a script to get assembler offsets to structures, etc.  So if a compiler packs structures differently, then in theory, the assembler will be in-sync with the compiler version.  We start here,

```
.L__vectors_start:
    W(b)    vector_rst
    W(b)    vector_und
    W(ldr)  pc, .L__vectors_start + 0x1000
    W(b)    vector_pabt
    W(b)    vector_dabt
    W(b)    vector_addrexcptn
    W(b)    vector_irq
    W(b)    vector_fiq
```

The `swi` is a vector handled by `W(ldr)    pc, .L__vectors_start + 0x1000`, so the code is 4k after the vector table.  This is `vector_swi` and you can see the code in [entry-common.S](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/kernel/entry-common.S#L163).  There are two methods of making a syscall.  The older one (OABI) encodes the call in the SWI instruction.  This is bad as the ICACHE must be examined as data (DCACHE).  The newer systems pass the syscall in r7.  There are two jump tables; `sys_call_table` and `sys_oabi_call_table` to handle OABI and the newer mechanism.  In both case, higher `__NR_SYSCALL_BASE` are special cased and use `arm_syscall` in [traps.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/kernel/traps.c#L591).  So `SYS_ERROR0` is the `case 0: /* branch through 0 */` code in traps.c.  The message **branch through zero** is printed (because user space jump to the reset vector which can be at address 0) and the user space gets a signal.

Comment: " The older one (OABI) encodes the call in the SWI instruction." - For the new mechanism( non OABI) SYS_ERROR0 value will be ignored ?

Comment: That is my understanding.  It needs to be in R7.  If you have a kernel without OABI compat and you have a vector page at zero and user space branches there, then you would have a random syscall which is buggy.

Comment: It could actually be exploitable as a stack overflow in a routine which restores R7 will also be able to set LR/PC to zero. Most ARM systems don't have the vector table at zero, but an attacker just needs to know this constant for a system.  But any `SWI` could be used for this purpose.  The vectors will **not** be randomized though.